# Actionscript 3 addchild to a button

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to achieve sort of like an "extender" to a button. I want it to be like a invisible mask, and when you click on it, its the same as clicking on a button directly. Is this possible with an addchild method? Also, if possible, without having to make extra addeventlistners for the mask, so that additional object is seen as that same button. I know it can be done using a simplebutton, but what about a fl.controls button?

Answer (score 0):

You an use either a **Sprite** or **Movieclip** as clickable button.

Create both the "button" part and the "mask" part within same MovieClip, and give that whole MC one event listener.

Example if called: `myMClip_Button`...

```
myMClip_Button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handler_Mouse_Click );
```

Later, to access / modify anything within the MovieClip, just use a path:

```
myMClip_Button.myButton = something;
myMClip_Button.myMask = something;
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this ; this.addChild(btnA);
                btnA.mouseEnabled = false;
                                    btnA.mouseChildren = false; But somehow add when you click through the button, that it clicks the button, so completely opposite of the method. You can click through it, but it'll stil trigger onclick property.